# using single AE title to more than one Ipaddress

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am using dcmtk for PACS server process. here I am using dcmqrscp exe . In that exe dcmqrscp.cfg file contain detail about hosttable , aetitle table and vendor table. In this  hostable i am create one Ae title . Now my question is Shall i use a single aetitle from different ipaddress ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **Part 8**, **Page 46** of the DICOM Standard, **Network Communication Support for Message Exchange**. [Link to document](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/pdf/part08.pdf)

1. A single Application Entity Title can be associated with multiple network addresses assigned to a single
   system (e.g., multi-homed host).
2. A single Application Entity Title can be associated with multiple TCP Ports using the same or different
   IP Addresses.
3. A single network access point (IP Address and TCP Port) can support multiple Application Entity Titles.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I see, Karthick, is the response to a C-MOVE based retrieve where the destination is an AETITLE.
If there is various IP associated to the same aetitle, wich destination IP address wil be used to send the requested images?